# My wifi router is of 5V and 0.6 ampere, can i use 12V 2ampere power adapter?

Tags: wifi-configuration

My wifi router is of 5V and 0.6 ampere, can i use 12V 2ampere power adapter for it??, because original power adapter is lost. Please help me out with this confusion??

Comment: If it requires 5V then it requires 5V. The only confusion is the one you're making.

Comment: You cannot substitute a higher (more than double) voltage in any environment . Do not do this.